# Can cardinality be used to express exactly one?

Tags: logic

If I wanted to express the statement in predicate logic: 'There is exactly one apple that is green.'
Would it be correct to say that if $x$ is an apple that is an element of $A$: {all apples} and that $G(x)$: $x$ is a green apple, that: 'There exists an apple $x$ that is an element of the set $A$, $|A|=1$, $G(x)$'?

Comment: $$\exists x(G(x)\land\forall y(G(y)\to y=x))$$

Comment: Your statement isn't really well-formed, but it seems to say "There is exactly one apple and it is green".  That's not what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Introducing sets and their sizes is not necessary. If, for $x$ in our universe of apples, $G(x)$ means $x$ is green, then $\exists x\forall y(G(y) \leftrightarrow x = y)$ is true iff there is exactly one green apple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't understand why it's not necessary to include the sets. Why don't we need to include that 'x' belongs to the set A? Also, am I reading your predicate statement correctly by saying, 'There exists a variable 'x', such that for all variables 'y', 'y ' are apples that are green if and only if x = y'?

Comment: @kooner3 In logic it is common to separate sentences from structures. Evaluating the sentence $(\exists x)(\forall y) \big( G(y) \leftrightarrow x=y \big)$ in the structure $A$ of all apples gives the required statement "there is exactly one green apple". In classical math you would rather write $(\exists x \in A)(\forall y \in A) \big( G(y) \leftrightarrow x=y \big)$ and not think about any particular structure. I wonder though - do all apples form a set or maybe a proper class?...